# ctypes: c_ulong type magically changed to long

Tags: python, ctypes

I am writing the **deepcopy** function using python2.7 for my class. I encountered a weird problem
My code is the following

```
import copy
from ctypes import *
class Graph (Structure):
    _fields_ = [("numVertices", c_ulong),
                    ("numEdges", c_ulong)]
    def __init__(self):
        self.numVertices = c_ulong(0)
        self.numEdges = c_ulong(0)

    def __deepcopy__(self,memo={}):
        newInstance = Graph()
        newInstance.numVertices = c_ulong(self.numVertices.value)
        newInstance.numEdges = c_ulong(self.numEdges.value)
        return newInstance

graph = Graph()
anotherGraph = copy.deepcopy(graph)
```

I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-46-a0cdaa4ef3f7> in __deepcopy__(self, memo)
      9     def __deepcopy__(self,memo={}):
     10         newInstance = Graph()
---> 11         newInstance.numVertices = c_ulong(self.numVertices.value)
     12         newInstance.numEdges = c_ulong(self.numEdges.value)
     13         return newInstance

AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'value'
```

If you try:

```
type(graph.numVertices)
```

The result is long

I declared the numVertices as c_ulong(). Why does it become long?

Comment: I know the type of the `value` attribute of c_ulong is long. But my question is that why a field of type c_ulong become type long. You see numVertices is of type c_ulong and it should have a value attribute. But in the `__deepcopy__` function its type becomes long instead of c_ulong and it doesn't have 'value' attribute at all!

Comment: I see what you mean. I removed my mistaken answer. It's interesting that you get the expected result once you remove `_fields_` from the class.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the fields in the structure is still maintained, but ctypes has some "helpful" conversions when reading the values:

```
from ctypes import *

class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a',c_ulong),
                ('b',c_char_p)]

t = Test(1,b'hello')
print(type(t.a),type(t.b))
print(t._fields_)
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'> <class 'bytes'>
[('a', <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>), ('b', <class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>)]
```

So you can write your code as the following and it will work correctly:

```
import copy
from ctypes import *
class Graph (Structure):
    _fields_ = [("numVertices", c_ulong),
                    ("numEdges", c_ulong)]
    def __init__(self):
        self.numVertices = 0
        self.numEdges = 0

    def __deepcopy__(self,memo={}):
        newInstance = Graph()
        newInstance.numVertices = self.numVertices
        newInstance.numEdges = self.numEdges
        return newInstance

graph = Graph()
anotherGraph = copy.deepcopy(graph)
```

You can suppress the conversions by deriving from the classes, but it is usually unnecessary.  One use case is when using ctypes to call a function that returns an allocated string.  You need to suppress the c_char_p to Python byte string conversion so you can later free the c_char_p.

```
from ctypes import *

class ulong(c_ulong): pass
class char_p(c_char_p): pass

class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a',ulong),
                ('b',char_p)]

t = Test(1,b'hello')
print(type(t.a),type(t.b))
print(t.a,t.b)
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.ulong'> <class '__main__.char_p'>
<ulong object at 0x0000000006263748> char_p(b'hello')
```